# Check if a point is part of an object

Tags: java, android, equals

I've got  a little question. I want to check if a point is part of an object / if the point is into the object ( for example an imageView ). Can I use "equals" ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html#equals(java.lang.Object) ? Does it mean the object only or even every point of the object?
Or is there an other way?
Thanks for every help

Comment: If you mean "Can I use `myPoint.equals(myObject)` to test if `myObject` contains `myPoint`, then no. The point is not _equal to_ an object that contains it.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean. Und s there any other way?

Comment: It depends what your object is and what methods it exposes. There's no general answer.

Comment: **No**. *A part is not equal to the whole*. Let your object implement a method such as `contains()` and you can tell wether a part is ***contained*** into an object or not.

Comment: If your object extends view, you can get its borders, and then make a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should work if you mean object, that extends View.

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        float startX = imageView.getX();
        float startY = imageView.getY();
        float endX = startX + imageView.getWidth();
        float endY = startY + imageView.getHeight();
        Point point = new Point(10, 10);                       //test point
        if ((point.x >= startX && point.x <= endX)
                && (point.y >= startY && point.y <= endY) ){
            Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + "is part of object");
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate: " + "is not part of object");
        }
```